# Enabling fast scroll on flutter's Scrollbar?

Tags: android, flutter, scroll

Android provides this concept of [fast scroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled(boolean)) what is useful for large lists.

I'm doing a flutter app, with this piece of code:

```dart
body: Scrollbar(
    child: ListView(
…
```

On iOS and on mac it is possible to drag the scrollbar and achieve the same effect of fast scroll, but on android the scroll bar is just visual, I can't interact with it to fast scrolling the list.

My question is: is it possible to enable the "fast scroll" on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to **make Scrollbar work** you have to set `interactive: true`. Please have a look below:

```
Scrollbar(
   thickness: 10,
   interactive: true,
   isAlwaysShown: true,
   controller: scrollController,
   child:ListView(),
)
```

(`thickness` and `isAlwaysShown` modified to make it easier for testing)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the scroll controllers. Give scrollController to both ScrollBar and ListView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Scrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Item: ${index + 1}"),
                  )
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code has the same issue, take a look to this code running on android, there is no fast scroll, look to me trying to drag the scrollbar: https://gfycat.com/floweryglumachillestang in other hand, the same code running on mac allows the fast scroll, look how I can drag the scroll bar on mac: https://gfycat.com/breakabledarlingblackpanther